# How to convert list<object> to String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, object

How can I convert a object list to a string array?

I tried the following code, but I get an ArrayStoreException Error

```
 List<Object> content = mdp.getContent(); //From docx4j API
 Object[] objectArray = content.toArray();
 String[] paragraphs = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);
```

Thanks

Comment: What are these `Object`s? Do they have useful `toString()` implementations?

Comment: Are the `Object`s in the List actually Strings, or do you want to call the toString method?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have just strings in your list, then it's a one-step operation:

```
content.toArray(new String[content.size()]);
```

Otherwise you'll have to iterate over each member, applying `toString()` or whichever method you must use to get the string representation of each list member. For that case there is no shortcut in the JDK.